# Large multipart/form-data cannot be transmitted to the back-end?

Tags: java, html, http, networking

This form has about 50 inputs, one of which may be empty or long.

When the input is empty, the form submits normally.

When the input is long, the data cannot be sent to the back-end. (This situation is a probabilistic event that cannot be stably reproduced in the process of reproduction).

Tracing the code we see that the request was already marked isEOF before it entered the file-upload.jar method. I suspected that it was a network problem because it could not be reproduced stfully.

I used Wireshark to capture the packets of this submission operation, and found that when the above exception was selected again, no HTTP packets were captured, so the packets inside could not be tracked.

Can you give me some advice on where to start to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: How large is the data in the failed submissions?

Comment: @DaveNewton Almost 3000 bytes